# Can someone identify this insect species

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found a dozen of these insects on my wooden floorboards in the city of Athens, Greece (Mediterranean climate) (altitude 200m, 10 km from nearest shore). Currently it's Autumn. Size is about 0.5cm (see photo below).

Can someone please identify the species?
[image]

Comment: (I've also noticed numerous shed wings)

Comment: Check if they are ants (queen or drone forms).